# Outlook 2010 is showing the "To Address" in the navigation pane

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This one is difficult to explain...
In the Outlook 2010 navigation pane I arrange my email by Date with the newest on the top. However each email preview,along with the subject, shows the "To" address instead of the "From" address.

This means that I have an inbox where all emails have the same address on them, my own, instead of the person who sent me the email.

Make sense?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on 'Arranged by: Date' (Or 'Arranged by: something else')->Custom->Fields

On the right hand column select 'To' and click remove.

Probably not the right place to ask this, more of a SuperUser thing maybe?